# Поднимаем GIT на своем домене и сервере

Tags: git, ubuntu

Добрый день. У нас есть домен вида git.site.com, а также сервер под управлением ОС Ubuntu Server 13.10. Сервер стоит за роутером Netgear JNR-3210 в локальной сети. Какой алгоритм действий нужно произвести, чтобы поднять GIT сервер так, чтобы любой сотрудник нашей компании мог из Интернета, а также из локальной сети (сейчас роутер раздает ip адреса автоматически), пользоваться GIT сервером?

Comment: Также интересует вопрос - какую папку лучше выбрать для GIT репозитория /var/www или /home/user/.git? Или это вообще не имеет значения?

Comment: никакие серверные данные и программы не должны находится в /хоум, чтобы там рельсы и прочие не думали. /хоум - это пользовательские данные, настройки его в плеера, возможно, хранилище музыки, но ничего исполняемого и репозитариев там быть не должно.

Comment: @Fike, почему бы нет, если для git-сервера выделен отдельный пользователь? те же authorized_keys надо ведь где-то хранить.

Я именно про данные, а не про исполняемые файлы.

Comment: @Nofate мускулу тоже много что надо хранить. Он же не лезет в пользовательские папки.  
Это банальное разделение логики. Пользователь git не является реальным пользователем, у него нет .bashrc, по такой логике половину /etc/ можно в /home переносить.  
(я ставил в свое время гитлаб не туда, куда он мечтал встать, и теперь негодую)

Comment: >  Пользователь git не является реальным пользователем, у него нет .bashrc, 

В случае с gitosis, например, очень даже есть.

Comment: Тут философия зависит от того, как вы рассматриваете git-репозиторий: как системный инструмент на сервере или как бизнес-приложение под которое этот сервер выделен.

Comment: Я немного не то имел в виду: svn и все остальные серверные приложения (не только системы контроля версий) без проблем избегают подобных паттернов. И я, честно говоря, не вижу ни единой причины его нарушать. Нет причин из приложения делать реального пользователя.

Comment: Да, у SVN  есть свой порт и работает она на своем протоколе. Она может не использовать подобный паттерн.

C  git-ом обычно работают по SSH. А это значит: выделенный пользователь, полноценный HOME  с `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, какой-нибудь `PATH` в `.bashrc` (для специфических хуков, например). Ну и почему бы не использовать эту же директорию, на которую у него уже есть права под репозиторий?

Comment: @Nofate, а разве это не через git-shell делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - поставить одним пакетом Atlassian Stash или GitLab. Будут у вас и проекты/репозитории, и веб-морда, и управление правами-ключами, и ssh с http из коробки.

Немного более "ручной" способ - поставить gitosis или gitolite.

> Сервер стоит за роутером Netgear JNR-3210 в локальной сети

Ну и порт (HTTP или SSH) вероятно придется пробросить через роутер.

Comment: Поставить одним пакетом - да, но прописывать config всё равно придётся. Стоит ли весь этот зоопарк необходимости просто иметь git репозиторий - каждый решает сам.

Comment: @pirj, конфиг чего?

Установка Stash-а на линях выглядит так: вы в командной строке запускаете установщик, у вас спросят пару параметров типа директории установки и номера портов для Tomcat-а. И все. Через пять минут вы уже в веб-интерфейсе создаете проекты.

Comment: >  Стоит ли весь этот зоопарк необходимости просто иметь git репозиторий - каждый решает сам.

Поверьте, возможность иметь "корпоративный GitHub" при минимуме усилий очень соблазнительна.

Comment: Было бы куда более соблазнительно научить сотрудников пользоваться командной строкой.

Comment: Веб-морда служит для коммуникации и управления - просмотр истории, инспектирование/комментирование кода, переход из описаний коммитов в тасктрекер, пул-реквесты, удобное управление правами, ключами, или, например, LDAP-авторизация.

> научить сотрудников пользоваться командной строкой.

При этом командная строка никуда не девается. Commit, merge, pull, push и все остальное вы по-прежнему делаете удобным вам способом.

Comment: Для промостра истории служит git log/blame, для комментирования кода служит емейл, для переходов из описаний коммитов служит терминал и браузер, для pull реквестов у разработчиков должен быть свой public репозиторий, для информирования - емейл, для удобного управления правами gitolite вполне окей. LDAP нигде не видел для авторизации в git'е. "Емейл" можно заменить на любой другой способ комуникаций. Остальное - рюшечки, лишь отнимающие время.

Comment: Кому-то удобнее пачка разных инструментов в разных местах, кому-то один централизованный. 

PS. Думаю очень весело на gitosis управлять несколькими десятками пользователей на разных проектах, которые еще и регулярно меняют ключи )

PPS. Собственно дискуссия началась с необходимости прописывания конфига. Так вот, можно обойтись и без этого )

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте вот эту главу http://git-scm.com/book/ru/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5 . Там хорошо написано про различные протоколы, их преимущества и недостатки, и как сконфигурировать каждый из них. Через роутер надо будет просто прокинуть порт до сервера, в зависимости от выбранного протокола. Например, для http это будет 80, а для git - 9418.